# Change the Display size of Image on Form resizing

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want that when i resize the form, Image Display resize with form size automatically

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.png";
        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            //pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        }
    }
```

Suggest me some code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

and

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

**Edit**

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

Comment: pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
this code is not maintain the ratio of image

Comment: Please suggest me some code that change the image Display size with maintaining the ratio. like Windows picture viewer

Comment: have you try using PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize? use both Dock as fill and SizeMode  as AutoSize

Comment: I have Try your suggestions, but it's not work like Windows picture viewer